# Non-invasive way to return multiple values from a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am dealing with a large code base and I am wondering what is a non-invasive way to add an extra return value to a function without changing all the uses. For example:

Existing setup:

```
def foo():
    return 'bar'

re = foo()
```

My attempt:

```
def foo():
    return 'bar', 'baz'


re, _ = foo()  # re has a correct value but I had to add `, _` in all uses
re    = foo()  # Error: re is now a tuple, thus semantic has changed.
```

Comment: If you change the return type of a function, you're going to have to change its usage everywhere it's used.

Comment: You can only ever return a *single value*, that value may be a 
container, like a tuple, like in your second example. Im not exactly sure what you are *expecting*. If you change the return value, then you can't expect to not have downstream effects, unless you change the value with some LSP compliant subtype

Comment: If you're making a breaking change to the return type of a function that others are using perhaps you should create a new function and optionally add a deprecation warning to the old function to allow others to migrate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very important to understand that you can only ever return a single value, that value may be a container, like a tuple, like in your second example. But it is always a single type.

If you change the return value, then you can't expect to not have downstream effects, unless you change the value to some [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) compliant subtype. In this case, you could return some *string subtype* with an extra attribute, if you don't want to break the downstream uses.

```
class StringWithMetadata(str):
    def __new__(cls, obj, metadata=None):
        return super().__new__(cls, obj)
    def __init__(self, obj, metadata=None):
        # note, ignoring obj
        self.metadata = metadata # or whatever appropriate name you want


def foo():
    return StringWithMetadata('bar', 'baz')

re = foo()
print(re, re.metadata)
```

Edit:

Seeing as you tagged this with Python 2.7 (you really should avoid this if you can), then you can either use the longform of `super`:

```
return super(StringWithMetadata, cls).__new__(cls, obj)
```

Or just the explicit way (which you could always do):

```
return str.__new__(cls, obj)
```

Comment: nice technique!

Comment: @PierreD yes, to be honest though, this is about the only use-case I would tolerate for a string subclass - i.e. just a string with some extra attributes of metadata. Honestly, this is just a bandaid over a design that was not adequately encapsulated, but that happens.

Answer (score 1):

If the intent is to *add instrumentation* to a function that has a a relatively large usage footprint (i.e., without changing all the code that uses that function), perhaps something along those lines might help:

```py
def foo(spy=None):
    result = 'bar'
    if isinstance(spy, dict):
        spy['ret'] = result
        spy['other'] = 'baz'
        # ...
    return result
```

Examples:

The original uses can remain unchanged:

```py
r = foo()
>>> r
'bar'
```

But you can also pass a dict to obtain some other info from within your function:

```py
spy = {}
r2 = foo(spy=spy)
>>> spy
{'ret': 'bar', 'other': 'baz'}
```

You can of course use other types for your "spy" container.